# NodeMCU v3 with TIP120 and DC booster

Tags: esp8266, solenoid-valve, nodemcu

I have already been through plenty of topics to try to integrate three TIP120s with a DC booster in order to operate two solenoids valves (non-latching NC ones). I think I am getting close but there are details it seems that I clearly haven't taken into account.

Currently, the project looks like this:

[image]

The project consists of a NodeMCU v3 (I cannot power the DC booster using Vin but Vu is working fine) controlling two valves. Everything is powered via USB via the NodeMCU input (5 V, 2.5 A transformer).

The aim is to have the DC booster turned off when no valve is activated, but to provide the necessary current for the solenoid valves depending on what circuit is requested: one, the other, or both.

The solenoid valves are normaly closed, non-latching ones; that is a requirement for the project as I need a safe fallback in any situation. They are rated for 12 V, 400 mA.

The booster is an MT3608 ([datasheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/1638/files/MT3608_Step_Up_Converter_Datenblatt_AZ-Delivery_Vertriebs_GmbH.pdf?v=1607619339)) DC turning 2-24 V into maximum 28 V with maximum 1 A output. That should be enough to power both valves if needed, and to raise the voltage above 12 V to account for the transistors' own consumption.

The code itself is not an issue, I have a simple HTTP, 2 endpoints API exposing the status of both valves (ON/OFF), and a function with a pin parameter to toggle the state of the designated pin. It works great.

What I have observed:

- With no load plugged (valves disconnected,) the expected voltage is correctly available when the pins are toggled via the API.
- With a load plugged, the voltage remains at 0 V, even when I request the activation, and despite the booster receiving power (4.3 V measured.)
- When no valve is activated, I can still read 1.5 V entering the DC booster.

This is my first project involving multiple transistors.  It works great with a single one. If I plug one valve directly into the DC booster, it works. This means one booster per valve, despite it being rated powerful enough for two.

Is this related to the booster not handling the load correctly, or the transistors not being saturated? I have read plenty of sources but I haven't figured out in what situation I am yet.

Comment: 5Vx2A = 10W power in.  24Vx1A = 24W out.  Does not work.

Comment: @JRE Why 24V x 1A? Isn't that the max power consumed? Isn't it something like 12V x 0,8A = 9,6W? I am taking your remark into account but with one load would it be enough to hit that wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close at it, but the boost converter is not isolated. So if you want to switch the GND path of the converter, this applies to both sides.

The "OR" function formed by the two diodes D5 and D6 must take the original MCU outputs, because there is not enough voltage left behind the 2.2 kohm base resistors.

Using TIP120 here is not very efficient, MOSFETs would perform better.

The inrush current of the boost converter may cause a voltage drop on the 5 V supply line. A big capacitor may be required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff3Mzb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>